# How to use following script to show element of the tree structure on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code to show the selected option from `<option>` tag:

```
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Flowers</option>
    <option>Shrubs</option>
    <option>Trees</option>
    <option>Bushes</option>
    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Dirt</option>
</select>

<div class="display_text_here"></div>

<script>
    $("select").change(function () {
    var str = ""; 
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
    str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $(".display_text_here").text(str);
    })
   .change();
</script>
```

Is it possible to use the same `<script>` for the folowing structure? When i click on a country becomes `<li class="tf-child-false tf-selected">`

```
<li>
    <div>Europe</div>
        <ul>
            <li tf-child-false tf-selected><div>United Kingdom</div></li> 
            <li><div>Sweden</div></li>
            <li><div>Germany</div></li>
            <li><div>France</div></li>
            <li><div>Spain</div></li>
            <li><div>Italy</div></li>
            <li><div>Austria</div></li>
            <li><div>Turkey</div></li>
            <li><div>Russia</div></li>
            <li><div>Denmark</div></li>
            <li><div>Finland</div></li>
            <li><div>Iceland</div></li>
            <li><div>Switzerland</div></li>
            <li><div>Hungary</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I've tried the following, but it's not working:

```
<script>
    $("ul").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("li class:tf-selected").each(function () {
    str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $(".display_ text_here").text(str);
    })
    .change();
</script>
```

Comment: `$("ul").change(function () {` impossible listener, ul cant change. you maybe can use `$("li").click(function () {`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind change on the "ul" tag.
You must bind the click on the ul and then check which "li" are selected like that :

```
//Here you should better use an ID for your "ul"
$("ul li").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('tf-selected');
    var str = "";
      $('ul li[class=tf-selected]').each(function (index, element) {
    str += $(element).text() + " ";
  });
  $(".display_text_here").text(str);
});
```

Comment: When i click on the tructure: Europe, all lines below Europe are also shown at same time. Becouse there is this line addClass. The point is, that those classes are already declared, when i click on Tab1 it's class active, when on Europe it's Class open, when on country (Italy) it's Class selected. Look at picture: http://postimg.org/image/6bun0m1hb/

So i need that king of script which will recognize which class is declared by click on Tag/Region/Country and wil write the result like this:

Active (Tab1)
   Open (Europe)
      Selected (Italy)

Answer (score 0):

Like i say in my comment : `$("ul").change(function () {` impossible listener, ul cant change. you maybe can use `$("li").click(function () {`

```
   $("li").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
          var str = "";
           $("li.tf-selected").each(function () {
               str += $(this).text() + " ";
           });
            $(".display_text_here").text(str);
    });
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/poignant_benjamin/kqfxLvda/

Comment: When i click on the tructure: Europe, all lines below Europe are also shown at same time. Becouse there is this line addClass. The point is, that those classes are already declared, when i click on Tab1 it's class active, when on Europe it's Class open, when on country (Italy) it's Class selected. Look at picture: http://postimg.org/image/6bun0m1hb/

So i need that king of script which will recognize which class is declared by click on Tag/Region/Country and wil write the result like this:

Active (Tab1)
   Open (Europe)
      Selected (Italy)

Answer (score 0):

I just find out the sollution, but have one little isue

```
<script>
    $("li").click(function () {
   <!-- $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
    var str = "";
    $("li.active").each(function () {
    str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
    });
    $(".display_text_here").text(str);
});
</script>

<script>
     $("li").click(function () {
    <!--    $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
     var str = "";
    $("li.tf-open").each(function () {
    str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
    });
    $(".display_text_here2").text(str);
    });
</script>

<script>
    $("li").click(function () {
    <!--    $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
    var str = "";
    $("li.tf-selected").each(function () {
    str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
    });
    $(".display_text_here3").text(str);
    });
</script>
<div class="display_text_here"></div> 
<div class="display_text_here2"></div> 
<div class="display_text_here3"></div>
```

There is this issue. I have a structure:

`Tag1
    Asia
       Southern-West
         India
         Pakistan
         Butan
       Southern-East
       Far-east
       Central
    Antarctica
    Africa
    Europe`

When i click on tag 1 (class active) and on india (class selected) works fine, but when i clcik on asia (class open) returns Asia Southern-West Southern-East Far-east Central  -- all of the tags below Asia...i need that it would return me just Asia, and when i select Southern-West just Southern-West. Like this:

Tag 1 (class active)
Asia (class open)
Southern-West (class open)
India (class selected)

If i select also from Tag 2 the same selection, there must be both selections for Tag1 and Tag2

Tag 2 (class active)
Asia (class open)
Southern-West (class open)
India (class selected)

After all, thanks both for great answer.